# Responsive Compile-and-Run Vim Mapping

Tags: mapping, vim

I have the following mapping in my .vimrc.

```
:nmap <F5> :<C-U>make %:r && ./%:r<CR>
```

I press F5 in VIM, and it compiles, exits VIM, and runs my code. When the program terminates, it asks me to "press ENTER or enter a command to continue." It then takes me to a blank screen with the text `(1 of 5):` and the same "press ENTER or enter a command to continue" prompt. I press enter and it finally returns me back to VIM. This behavior is consistent across the board. Is there a way to remove any or both of those occurrences? Perhaps have the mapping press ENTER twice after the program terminates? If so, how?

**EDIT:** So I realized appending two more `<CR>`'s doesn't quite solve the problem. As soon as the program terminates, it IMMEDIATELY goes back to VIM and I don't have time to review the output. Can I make the mapping wait for ME to press the first enter, and automatically press the 2nd ENTER afterwards?

Comment: I don't see this behavior, just one prompt.  Can you post your .vimrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work:

`nmap <F5> :<C-U>silent make %:r<CR>:redraw!<CR>:!./%:r<CR>`

A longer solution but this one also allows you to see errors ([reference](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.vim/60571)):

```
:function! MakeAndRun()
:        silent make %:r
:        redraw!
:        if len(getqflist()) == 1
:          !./%:r
:        else
:          for i in getqflist()
:            if i['valid']
:                 cwin
:                 winc p
:                 return
:            endif
:          endfor
:        endif
:endfunction
:nmap <F5> :call MakeAndRun()<cr>
```

Comment: Your first suggestion works perfectly! I press F5, it compiles and runs; after termination it waits for me to press enter (once!) before returning back to file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes (you answered your own question):

```
:nmap <F5> :<C-U>make %:r && ./%:r<CR><CR>
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realized the <CR> was the 'ENTER.' It brought up a new problem though. Please see the question edit.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works fine:

```
" Compile
noremap <F4> :<C-U>silent make<CR>:redraw!<CR>
" Automatically open, but do not go to (if there are errors) the quickfix /
" location list window, or close it when is has become empty.
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* nested cwindow
autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* nested lwindow
```

It compiles, and immediately jumps to vim, showing the quickfix window. No intermediate enters.